# Does ehad mean "one" or "first" when used together with "rishon"?

Tags: words, hebrew, tanach

How should ehad be translated in this phrase and why?

> וְשַׂ֣ר׀ מַלְכ֣וּת פָּרַ֗ס עֹמֵ֤ד לְנֶגְדִּי֙ עֶשְׂרִ֣ים וְאֶחָ֣ד י֔וֹם וְהִנֵּ֣ה מִֽיכָאֵ֗ל **אַחַ֛ד הַשָּׂרִ֥ים הָרִאשֹׁנִ֖ים** בָּ֣א לְעָזְרֵ֑נִי וַאֲנִי֙ נוֹתַ֣רְתִּי שָׁ֔ם אֵ֖צֶל מַלְכֵ֥י פָרָֽס׃
> [(Daniel 10:13)](https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.10.13?lang=bi)

Some english translations of tanach say "one of the chief princes" while some say "first of the chief princes."

Why are both ehad and rishon translated differently in this sentence:

> וַיְכַלּ֣וּ בַכֹּ֔ל אֲנָשִׁ֕ים הַהֹשִׁ֖יבוּ נָשִׁ֣ים נָכְרִיּ֑וֹת עַ֛ד **י֥וֹם אֶחָ֖ד לַחֹ֥דֶשׁ הָרִאשֽׁוֹן**
> [(Ezra 10:17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.10.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> **בְּיוֹם־ הַחֹ֥דֶשׁ הָרִאשׁ֖וֹן בְּאֶחָ֣ד לַחֹ֑דֶשׁ** תָּקִ֕ים אֶת־ מִשְׁכַּ֖ן אֹ֥הֶל מוֹעֵֽד
> [(Exodus 40:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.40.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Often translated as: "the first day of the first month"

How would you say "first of the first"?

Comment: As far as the date *day one of the first month* is the literal translation of אֶחָ֖ד לַחֹ֥דֶשׁ .הָרִאשֽׁוֹן

Comment: Interesting question. Can you [edit] in where your quotes are from, so people can look up commentaries on those verses?

Comment: Regarding your first quote (which is from Daniel 10:13): The [JPS 1917 as used by Mechon Mamre](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3410.htm#13) has "one of the chief princes", the [Judaica Press bible as brought by Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16493#v13) has "one of the first princes", and [Sefaria also offers](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.10.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "a prince of the first rank", "one of the foremost princes" or "one of the chief angels". Who translates it as "first of the chief princes"?

Comment: There are two different constructions here: echad אֶחָד and achad אַחַד

Comment: @TamirEvan  I don't know who translates like this, but it's legit, וּמִ֤י כְעַמְּךָ֙ כְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל גּ֥וֹי אֶחָ֖ד בָּאָ֑רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֣ר הָלְכֽוּ־אֱ֠לֹהִים לִפְדּֽוֹת־ל֨וֹ לְעָ֜ם וְלָשׂ֧וּם ל֣וֹ שֵׁ֗ם וְלַעֲשׂ֨וֹת לָכֶ֜ם הַגְּדוּלָּ֤ה וְנֹֽרָאוֹת֙ לְאַרְצֶ֔ךָ מִפְּנֵ֣י עַמְּךָ֗ אֲשֶׁ֨ר פָּדִ֤יתָ לְּךָ֙ מִמִּצְרַ֔יִם גּוֹיִ֖ם וֵאלֹהָֽיו׃

Comment: @AlaychemgoestoCodidact (1) Just because 'אחד' can be translated as 'first' in some places, when used on it's own, doesn't necessarily mean it is legit to translate 'אחד השרים הראשונים' as 'first of the chief princes', especially in that verse. (2) Knowing the translation's source (especially when not one of the common go-to Jewish sources of Biblical translations on this site) could help in evaluating it's relevance. More [relevant] information in a question is [usually] a good thing. No?

Comment: @TamirEvan 1) I agree. I didn't say it's the only right interpretation, only it's legit.